# Libsass error: UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character

Tags: python, flask, libsass

After upgrading my ubuntu inside VM to 14.04 - I started getting this error in pyCharm

`UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\ue94b' in position 66818: ordinal not in range(128)`

It comes from libsass trying to compile a scss folder with icons. It had no problems doing that before I upgraded to 14.04.

Comment: What version of Python are you using? What version were you using before?

Comment: @Phylogenesis 2.7.6 before and after upgrade. The version has not changed, just the ubuntu that went from 12.x to 14.x